# Settings for max velocity and acceleration not effected at real FANUC robot

Tags: ros, acceleration, fanuc, velocity, limits

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the the python commands `set_max_acceleration_scaling_factor(x)` and `set_max_velocity_scaling_factor(y)` of the MoveGroupCommander class to control the speed behaviour of a FANUC robot, based on the industrial package.

This works finse in a simulation only environment in RViz accordingly to the joint limits defined in the file `joint_limits.yaml`. But if I connect ROS to the controller of the real robot, the robot is much more slowly. The robot does not seem to follow the max factors. Are there additional limits defined in the FANUC industrial package?

Thanks in advance!

nico

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390670/settings-for-max-velocity-and-acceleration-not-effected-at-real-fanuc-robot/) by [nicob](https://answers.ros.org/users/85320/nicob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2021-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're using `fanuc_driver` (you don't state which package you're using, but I assume it's that one), then it overrides the velocity commands. That's a limitation of that driver.

[gavanderhoorn/fanuc_driver_exp](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/fanuc_driver_exp) tries to do better, and it will not override anything, but motion performance will still not be perfect.

There is a lot of existing Q&A and discussion on the issue tracker of both `ros-industrial/fanuc` and `gavanderhoorn/fanuc_driver_exp` which I don't want to repeat here. Summarising: except `J519`, there is no Fanuc motion interface which allows you to execute trajectories *exactly* as they are planned on the ROS side. That's both in time and in space. Off-line generation of TP programs based on ROS trajectories is possible (and has been done), but of course comes with its own disadvantages (limited length, programs need to be uploaded, delays before execution, etc).

An alternative could be a driver based on `R912` (or *Remote Motion Interface*, RMI). That would essentially be a "drip-feed" of a TP program. I'm not aware of any publicly available implementation based on `R912` though.

And note that again except with `J519`, you can never actually directly control velocity nor acceleration on a Fanuc. You only ever constrain *maximum* velocity, and can indirectly set the steepness of the *acceleration curve*.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-11-11**:
See #q371112 for a similar Q&A, and see [this page](https://answers.ros.org/questions/scope:all/sort:activity-desc/tags:fanuc/page:1/) for more Fanuc related ROS questions (some / many of which are on similar topics).

**Comment by [nicob](https://answers.ros.org/users/85320/nicob/) on 2021-11-15**:
Thanks for de detailed answer! This helps me a lot to understand the system better.